# What is wrong with the devil?

Tags: shaitan

I don't get it, shaitan, iblis, devil, lucifer, whatever you want to call him doesn't need blind faith to know god exists.  I don't know if he's seen god directly, but he has definitely seen what god can do and felt his power, and even heard and has followed his direct orders.  He can probably appreciate the power of god better than any man, he has I'm guessing has seen heaven and hell too.

Yet he still went against a direct order of god.  Why?  Is he stupid or something?  i.e. I don't think any man can be stupid enough not to follow a direct order of god if he knew everything the shaitan knew.  I don't think any man who would heard gods worlds directly would be stupid enough to disobey him no matter how much pride he had in his heart.

What's the deal, is the shaitan mentally retarded or something?

So god and the devil made a pact, i.e. that the devil will be given permission to whisper into mans ear will judgement day to lead him off the right path, without physically or mentally influencing him, i.e. all the devil can do is whisper stuff into your ears to give help you create ideas in your own mind.  And it is 100% your choice to act upon your thoughts.

So if the devil can stick to this agreement without breaking it, why not break the pact?  if he has no issue in disobeying a direct order of god?

Comment: Shaitan know his path is wrong, but his mentality does not allow him to respect the GOD

Comment: But he is respecting god by keeping to and not breaking the pact they made.

Comment: It is not a respect, he agree it only because there is no other choice

Comment: From time to time I ask my self almost the same question, What's wrong with me ? Maybe you should try redesign your question, I do not know does We allowed to discuss about Allah's relationships with Shaitan(s).

Comment: I don't really think it wasa a pact, it was more like Syaitan vowing vengeance on Adam's children and Allah allowing this. It was arrogance. Shaitan was given a lot of power, to the point where he refused to bow before Allah's creation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The devil was one the "Jin" (creatures made of fire) and had a chance to be with angels. However when God created Adam, human from dust:

> Indeed, the example of Jesus to Allah is like that of Adam. He created Him from dust; then He said to him, "Be," and he was. [Surat 3: Ayah 59](http://quran.com/3/59)

and asked them to Prostrate before him:

> And [mention] when We said to the angels, "Prostrate to Adam," and they prostrated, except for Iblees. He was of the jinn and departed from the command of his Lord. Then will you take him and his descendants as allies other than Me while they are enemies to you? Wretched it is for the wrongdoers as an exchange. [Surat 18: Ayah 50](http://quran.com/18/50)

he became arrogant and a disbeliever:

> [ Allah ] said, "What prevented you from prostrating when I commanded you?" [Satan] said, "I am better than him. You created me from fire and created him from clay." [Surat 7: Ayah 12](http://quran.com/7/12)

So this is why...

PS: Your post is quite funny.

Comment: JKK, what does disbeliever mean in this case?  I'm sure the devil believes that god exists.

Comment: He became a disbeliever by disobeying God's orders. Disbelieving in God isn't just from "believing" that he doesn't exist, but also not believing in his holy names by in this case thinking that he knows more and his judgement is better than Gods.
And Allah know best

Answer (score 3):

### "...why not break the pact? if he has no issue in disobeying a direct order of god?"

First let me explain this "pact" between Allah and the devil

> [Iblees] said, "My Lord, because You have put me in error, I will surely make [disobedience] attractive to them on earth, and I will mislead them all" 15:39

This isnt a typical agreement, treaty or contract, the reason why the devil is trying to mislead us is for revenge.

Now you ask why dosent the devil break this "agreement?" **its not really an agreement** its revenge Allah Never said "I give permission for you to do so" during this whole process of revenge he dosent have Allahs consent to be misleading us. In other words he is breaking allah command, and he has never stopped.There isnt an agreement between them. Also, nowhere suggets that the devil has the power to force us to sin, even in the beggining he used his words to pursuade adam and eve.

Now let me explain what exactly is the relationship between the devil, Allah, and the people. As the ayah mentioned above, this is all a process of revenge. So why dosent allah just stop it? The proceeding ayats explain:

> Indeed, My servants - no authority will you have over them, except those who follow you of the deviators.And indeed, Hell is the promised place for them all 15:42-43

Allah is trying to disprove the devil, He is showing him that there is hope for this nation, that we will rebel against the devils words, and follow the Almighty lord. But those who dont will be punished, because we fell into the traps of the devil with our own will. The devil in this situation is trying to do the exact opposite, he is showing allah that his "faithful" servents, will instantly listen to what he says, so its a bonus that they are doing it at their own will, and not forcibly.

So in conclusion the devil dosent posses the power to force us to sin its not that he is following an agreement, and the fact that people sin on their own makes it better for the devil, because it angers Allah to know that they did so.

Comment: Nice answer, I really like it.  It does beg the question though, that if Allah didn't "allow" it, does that question omnipotence?

Comment: i didnt say god didnt allow it as in he tried to stop it i mean he didnt approve of it, but later i explained the reason why it was allowed to go on it because it distinguishes the good and evil people amoung us, and god will disprove the devil and show we can resist the devils power

Answer (score 1):

#### What was the cause of disobeying order?

You said, ..

> Yet he still went against a direct order of god. Why? Is he stupid or something?

I think, The ***Main*** cause of Shaitain which influence him to disobey the direct order of Almighty Allah, The creator of All, The Owner of All, Subhanahu-wa-ta'la was ***arrogance*** i.e pride, vanity, *egoism*. I would like to put emphasis on the word *egoism*. This word is more closer to his situation. The indicence of his disobiedience and arrogance is reflected in this ayat

> And  when We said to the angels, "Prostrate before Adam"; so they prostrated, except for Iblees. He refused and was arrogant and became of the disbelievers. <sup>[source](http://quran.com/2/34)</sup>

It is clear from this ayat is, He was proud and arrogant and refused to prostrate Adam.

**Cause of his arrogance**

The cause of his arrogance was, he thought and considered himself better than Adam *(indeed this is the main cause of creation of arrogance and pride in most of us)* because, He was made from Fire and Adam was made from earth/clay. This cause is narrated by himself!. Quran quoting his words:

> [ Allah ] said, "What prevented you from prostrating when I commanded you?" [Satan] said, "I am better than him. You created me from fire and created him from clay." <sup>[source](http://quran.com/7/12)</sup>

I was also told that, He said, Fire always go up and clay go down even if you throw it up.

Huzzatul Islam (*The proof of Islam*) Imam Gazzali (Rahimahu-Allah) wrote in his Great book (Ih-ya-u-uloom-id-din), Once prophet Musa (A.S) saw Saitain and Saitain said,"I want to repent, please seek forgiveness for me from Allah". Allah said in reply to Musa's request to forgive him, "Say him, to prostrate Adam's Grave". Hearing this, He strong and quickly refused to do so, saying "I didn't prostrate living Adam, How can I prostrate Adam after his death. It's impossible"

Another cause was, As He was made the leader of Angels because of his excessive worship <sup>[source](http://islamqa.org/?p=12340)</sup> *(It is said that, there is no place in the heaven where saitain did not give sajdah to Allah)* and Jinn and from his knowledge he forseen that, Mankind is going to be the Kalif of Allah in earth and he thought, He will no longer be preferred.

#### Did God make a pact?

> So god and the devil made a pact...

No, never, God didn't make a pact. A pact can be made with equal parties. There is absolutely no power of Saitain in front of Allah. He fear Allah too much<sup>[link](http://quran.com/59/16)</sup> and he knows his power also. He just seek a time period before his punishment and Allah gave him this chance. (Allah wants to test mankind with him)

> [Satan] said, "Reprieve me until the Day they are resurrected." <sup>[source](http://quran.com/7/14)</sup>

and Allah answered:

> [ Allah ] said, "Indeed, you are of those reprieved." 7:15

Allah has given him chance, so that We can be tested.

**And Allah knows all and best, He is the all-knower.**